# Keeping Tooltip and hover over after outputting Tableau

Tags: javascript, jpeg, tableau-api

I am currently new to Tableau and I am wondering if there is a way to simply keep the tooltip functionality of tableau when you output it? I am running Tableau on the mac so I think Tableau server is out of the question. Will tableau create JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest alternative, if you don't use Tableau Server, is to export your workbook as .twbx to share with other people, who will be able to open the file with Tableau Reader (which is free).

You can check Tableau JS API. I don't know it too well, but I guess it may not give what you need.

http://www.tableausoftware.com/new-features/javascript-api